# IBM Watson Speech-to-Text Python, 'DetailedResponse' object has no attribute 'getResult'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ibm-watson

I'm designing a project in Flask with Python that utilizes IBM Watson's Speech-to-Text feature. All I'm trying to do for now is load a FLAC file (0001.flac), interpret the file through Watson, and print the results to my console. I have the following code written thus far (I replaced my username and password for the example):

```
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import pprint, json, os
from watson_developer_cloud import SpeechToTextV1

. . .

speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
username='My username is here',
password='My password is here')

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '0001.flac'), 'rb') as audio_file:
    speech_to_text.set_detailed_response(True)
    outthis = speech_to_text.recognize(
          audio_file, content_type='audio/flac', timestamps=True)
    pprint.pprint(json.dumps(outthis.getResult(), indent=2))
```

And here is my output:

```
[2018-09-13 11:46:36,553] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ehill\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ehill\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\ehill\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\ehill\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\ehill\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\ehill\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\ehill\source\repos\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\FlaskWebProject1\views.py", line 31, in home
    pprint.pprint(json.dumps(outthis.getResult(), indent=2))
AttributeError: 'DetailedResponse' object has no attribute 'getResult'
```

According to the Watson documentation (https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/python.html?python#introduction) I should be able to receive information through getResult on a DetailedResponse object. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am seeing the same thing from our CI environment, which runs "pip install" from a clean environment.  It looks like a breaking changed introduced with watson_developer_cloud v2.0.0 (https://pypi.org/project/watson-developer-cloud/2.0.0/#changes-for-v2.0).

I've addressed for the time being by forcing version 1.7.1 until I can go look deeper at the code changes.  It looks like it might be a small-ish change (from a response.get to a response.get_result, but I cannot be sure of that).

FYI - here's the list of breaking changes in 2.0 release: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/wiki/Migration

Answer (score 0):

To adhere to [PEP8 conventions for function and variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), the `getResult` method was renamed to `get_result` in v2.0.